# Always returning a SMTP email address for Outlook Recipient

Tags: vba, outlook, mapi

I have seen a few posts on here where people are asking to find the recipient email address and are referred to the MAPI property : http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E" . However, as some users have pointed our not all MAPI properties are guaranteed to be there. So I am looking to develop a function which finds the correct method to get this email address. For senders email address I am able to tell if its an exchange user and get back the SMTP email address. Is there a method on here to return this regardless of if MAPI is missing?

Here is what I have so far

```
Public Function RecipientSMTPEmailAddress(outRecip As Outlook.Recipient) As String

On Error GoTo MissingMAPIError
RecipientSMTPEmailAddress = outRecip.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E")

Exit Function
MissingMAPIError:

RecipientSMTPEmailAddress = outRecip.Address

End Function
```

I am looking for a method similar to this used for the sender info:

```
 If OutMail.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
      SenderInfo = OutMail.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
 Else
      SenderInfo = OutMail.SenderEmailAddress
 End If
```

If there is a better way to ensure I get the SMTP email address I am all ears!

*Edited 9/23/2019 - New and Improved code to catch all recipient errors

```
Public Function RecipientSMTPEmailAddress(outRecip As Outlook.Recipient) As String

On Error GoTo MissingMAPIError

RecipientSMTPEmailAddress = outRecip.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E")

Exit Function

MissingMAPIError:

RecipientSMTPEmailAddress = RecipientSMTPEmailAddressExchange(outRecip)

End Function
Public Function RecipientSMTPEmailAddressExchange(outRecip As Outlook.Recipient) As String

On Error GoTo MissingExchangeError

RecipientSMTPEmailAddressExchange = outRecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress

Exit Function

MissingExchangeError:

RecipientSMTPEmailAddressExchange = ""

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `PR_SMTP_ADDRESS` property is missing, use `Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddrress` (be prepared to handle nulls and exceptions).

Comment: Don't I need to first check if its an exchange user? If so whats the function tor that similar to SenderEmailType? I have tried type but it retuns the type of sender in regards to a To, cc, bcc.

Comment: I check the outrecip.address for one missing the MAPI entry and also draws a "Object doesn't support this property or method
upport this property or method
" error an error using the method you mentioned. If i return just the outRecip.address it comes up with this (i changed the characters around obviously but overall not sure if this reveals anything):  "/o=ExchangeLabs/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FDSAFASDFASD33DFDF)/cn=Recipients/cn=djfaksld;fjaksldfjakl;sdjfla;sjdfl;af" . This user has to have an smtp address right?

Comment: Which method is causing the "Object doesn't support this property" error?

Comment: So as shown in the code I first check MAPI then if it causes error from missing to goes to error catch which then I do Outrecip.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddrress which draws the error.

Comment: Instead of using multiple dot notation, break that statement into multiple statement to know for sure. Most likely that happens because either Outrecip.AddressEntry returns null or AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser() returns null (and you never check that the return value is valid). This can happen if you are trying to access a GAL recipient from a profile that either does not have an Exchange server, or it does not contain the Exchange where that address entry was originally originated.

Comment: So it was the parenthesis which was triggering the error. I have edited my function above. I think this should be a catch all but I would be very thankful if you can think of any good additions to the code added above. Thanks for all your help.